# How to check existing record before saving in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, nested-attributes

I'm currently working on a simple Rails 4 app where I have these two related models:

`book.rb`

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
end
```

`author.rb`

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end
```

What I need to do is to check if the author exists already and if it does, use it on the book.

My `books_controller.rb`

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    @book = Book.new(BookParams.build(params)) # Uses class for strong params 

    if @book.save
      redirect_to @book, notice: t('alerts.success')
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to deal with this scenario without having duplicate author records? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work by using the code below:

`models/book.rb`

```
def author_attributes=(value)
  self.author = Author.find_or_create_by(value)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a `before_save` callback in the `Book` model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  before_save :merge_author

  private

  def merge_author
    if (author = Author.find_by(name: self.author.name))
      self.author = author
    end
  end
end
```

Note here that I am assuming here that your `Author` model has a `name` field which identifies each author. Perhaps you want to have another mechanism to determine if the author already exists.

However, [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) can also help you ensure that you have no duplicated records in your `Author` model.

Comment: Yes, name field us present in my model. I'm using this approach before in Rails 3.x however, in Rails 4, it causes duplicate author records. I'll test this again on a separate scaffold project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding but try to clearify the problem a little more please.

From my point of view you have to make sure yourself that you don't have duplicate records. In Rails you can use Validations in that case.

[Rails Guides Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness)

On the other hand what you are trying to solve looks like building/creating an ActiveRecord object through an ActiveRecord association. You have a Rails way for that, too.

[Rails Guides Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

Next there a callbacks, nested routes/controllers aso that fit to different requirements. You find Rails Guides for them, too. Of course it can be a combination of everything =)
And you have nested attributes as well which might have to be considered. cheers